# calling some function of an existing firefox extension (tamper data)

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, call

I'm developing a Firefox extension using an existing extension (tamper data). My extension need to call some function existing in the source code of Tamperdata, the question is : how can i call these functions?

Here's the code that I'm using to call these functions:

```
<menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">


      <menu xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" id="GetHttps" label="GetHttps" accesskey="">
        <menupopup id="menu_gethttps_Popup">
           <menuitem id="lancertamper" label="Run TamperData" oncommand="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
           <menuitem id="arreter TamperData" label="tampering" oncommand="xxxxxxxxxx"/>
        </menupopup>
      </menu>



     </menupopup>
```

there is a solution with using DOM?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "developing using an existing extension". Can you elaborate?

Comment: How to call a Javascript function declared in another firefox extension ( https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) from my extension